# Dll functions' names error when using ctypes

Tags: python, c++, c, dll, ctypes

I am given a DLL that was made by another person and I **can't access** its original .cpp and .h file. Based on a description file that describes the DLL functions' names, I am going to call them with Python using ctypes:

```
from ctypes import *

cppdll = WinDLL("C:\\VS_projects\\MusicServer_Flask\\NetServerInterface.dll")
py_InitNetwork = cppdll.InitNetwork
```

However, I failed to call these functions with this Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 360, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: function 'InitNetwork' not found
```

I thought there may be some problems with the function's name. So I used Dependency Walker to check the dll functions' names. As expected, the functions' names are strange(the `InitNetwork` becomes `?InitNetwork@@YAHQAD0H@Z`):

[image]

I searched online and found that there was something wrong during the compiling process when making this DLL.

Here is my question: Is letting the provider recompile the DLL the only way to solve this problem? Or is there another way to let me call these functions in Python?

Comment: I think the real problem here is not a name mangling, but the lack of C interface.

Answer (score 0):

The DLL seems to provide an interface to C++ functions. That's were the "strange" names come from.

Just recompiling won't help.

> ... is there another way to let me call these functions in Python?

One could use C++ to write a wrapper DLL, which exposed a C interface.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. So you suggest me to write a another C++ DLL that calls the functions in the original DLL and use Python to call the new C++ DLL?

Comment: @YQ.Wang: Yes, but you need to make sure *the wrapper DLL **exposes C** functions*. So I'd tend to not call the wrapper DLL a C++ DLL, but well ...